# Jenkins Plugin for Distributed api testing

Tags: java, maven, testing, jenkins

Is there any plugin in Jenkins for distributing api tests to slave machines in distributed fashion and returning back the results to the master? The plugin should work in a agent-less manner or agent based manner. We have a suite of api tests and intend to pass particular .class files to testng . Is there any plugin that will distribute these test case class files and perform api testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can create tests with JMeter and then use Jenkins Performance plugin to display results. More details on https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin